# How to change text in Text element

Tags: java, svg, svg-salamander

I have this line in my SVG file:

```
<text id="region1Text" class="regionText" x="77" y="167">2</text>
```

I can get an object of Text class with this but I cant see any usable method for changing "2" to another number. The appendText method seems to do nothing and I see there is no "setText" method.

My code:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(svgInString);
uri = SVGCache.getSVGUniverse().loadSVG(reader, "myImage");
SVGDiagram diagram = SVGCache.getSVGUniverse().getDiagram(uri); 
Text text = (Text) diagram.getElement("region1Text");
text.appendText("20");
```

When debugging I can see the content variable of the text object is set to "2"(so I think that text element is made correctly) but I'm not able to change it.

Comment: Please add your code which does it. we need to understand how you do it.

Comment: I have added piece of code as I rememember it. (maybe its not runnable but I think that I have right element in text object.

Comment: Which `Text` Api are you using?

Comment: I use Text from https://svgsalamander.java.net/, same as svg library

Answer (score 0):

After appending the text, you have to use `text.rebuild()` function. In total it looks like this:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(svgInString);
uri = SVGCache.getSVGUniverse().loadSVG(reader, "myImage");
SVGDiagram diagram = SVGCache.getSVGUniverse().getDiagram(uri); 
Text text = (Text) diagram.getElement("region1Text");
text.appendText("20");
text.rebuild();
```