# Clear text on SVG text

Tags: java, svg, svg-salamander

I am working with a java project, which it uses an SVG element from SVG Salamander lib and this element uses a Text form. The program writes on the text when a device is disconnected, using `Text.append()` the following legend is added

> No Data from the device:
>   Blockquote

but when the device is again reconnected this legend should be gone, but using `text.append("")`, the old message is still there. I've read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005481/how-to-change-text-in-text-element-java-salamander-svg). At the end, the question is how to clear the text from SVGElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Text class](https://github.com/blackears/svgSalamander/blob/master/svg-core/src/main/java/com/kitfox/svg/Text.java) has a [linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) content member.

To append to the list you append to the content member so to delete content you need to remove things from content. To delete everything therefore you'd want to call

```
text.getContent().clear();
```